# using grep to only print the lines confirmed by the if

Tags: linux, shell

I have a question where I need to print only the lines that the if statement confirms, but
can´t do that...

```
nr_registos=$2
geRegistos=$(  cat relatorio_utilizacao.txt | awk -F: '{if("$nr_registos" -ge $1)print$2}' | sort | uniq )
```

here the $1 is the first field of the file, while the nr_registos is the second argument that I give

this prints the $2 if the if statement is true, but I want only to print the lines where the if statement is true

Comment: This `$1` in `awk` code is for 1st field OR its 1st argument passed to script? It will be great if you put samples of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: The shell doesn't do environment variable substitution in single-quoted strings (like `$nr_registos` in your AWK command). You're comparing the literal string `"$nr_registos"` with the first field of each record (line) in the input file.